# How can I make this code print how many prime digits there are in a number?

Tags: java, logic, primes

The difference between the problem I have and every response I have gotten for this so far is that I'm trying make the code print how many of the digits are prime, not how many prime numbers are in the original number. For example if the user enters 567 I need to test 5, 6, and 7 and tell how many are prime.

Anyways- I'm trying to make this code print how many prime digits there are in a number the user enters. When I run it it prints The number has (a number) prime numbers. but it usually prints the wrong number each time I run it. I think if I just switch some of the variables for another variable and it will be good to go but I can't figure out which ones I need to change.
+edit: I'm pretty sure I need to change the value of `theNum` each time but I'm not sure how I can do that. I tried changing `x++` to `theNum%10` but it said x has to be increased. btw I'm doing `theNum%10` because I need to test each digit of `theNum` separately.

```java
int choice = 3, theNum, copy, x, y, counter, even, odd, zero;

System.out.print("Please enter a positive number ");
theNum = Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());

case 3:
    // using nested for loops print the prime numbers 
    counter = 0;
    for (x = 1; x <= theNum; x++) {
        for (x = 2; x <= theNum; x++) {
            if (theNum % 10 % x == 0) counter++;
        }
    }
    System.out.print("The number has " + counter + " prime numbers.");
    break;
```

Comment: what do you think that `theNum%10%x == 0` is a prime number?  e.g. is 10 or 20 prime numbers?

Comment: **HINT** *The only single-digit prime numbers are: 2, 3, 5, and 7.*

Comment: Also the value of `theNum` does not even change

Comment: How can I make theNum change?

Comment: This link may help you <https://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/java-program-to-display-prime-numbers/>.     Only add your count_prime_number variable in if(counter==2) statement and change the loop value w.r.t your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        int theNum,counter=0,remainder;      

        System.out.print("Please enter a positive number ");
        theNum = Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());  

        while(theNum>0) {
            remainder = theNum%10;

            if(isPrime(remainder))
                counter++;

            theNum = theNum/10;
        }      
        System.out.print("The number has " + counter + " prime numbers.");
    }

    static boolean isPrime(int n) 
    { 
        if (n <= 1) return false; 

        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) 
            if (n % i == 0) 
                return false; 

        return true; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something simple like predefine the known prime digits (since there are so few):

```
import java.util.*;

class Example {

    static Set<Integer> primeDigits = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(2, 3, 5, 7));

    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter a positive number: ");

        int theNum = Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());

        int counter = 0;

        while (theNum > 0) {
            if (primeDigits.contains(theNum % 10))
            {
                counter++;
            }

            theNum /= 10;
        }

        System.out.println("The number has " + counter + " prime digits.");
    }
}
```

**USAGE**

```
% java Example
Please enter a positive number: 2147483647
The number has 4 prime digits.
%
```